# How to configure compiler for WSL and visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am new to linux, c++, and visual studio code. Right now, the compiler I have installed does not match the required year for my class, which is g++ 2017. I am wondering how to add the compiler, which is on the linux environment, to visual studio code.

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know there's no such a thing as g++2017. Please give (quite) the exact instructions you were given. Also, have you searched the Internet for the answer? For example, the first result: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux ?

Answer (score 3):

You can start here:

[Using C++ and WSL in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl)

There is a VSCode extension [Remote - WSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) that simplifies the setup.

Don't worry about the exact compiler version, a newer version should work fine (better even).